# jQuery code not working correctly in Firefox

Tags: jquery

This code is working perfectly in Chrome, but it has some problem in Firefox (both newest version).
See in Jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/fasuxofavo/1/edit

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".typinganswer input").on('keypress', function(e)
{
    if(e.keyCode==13){
        alert("finish");
    }

    if($(this).val('') != "")
        $(this).val('');

    if($(this).is(':last-child'))
        $(this).select();

    $(this).next().select();

})
.on('keyup',function(e)
{
    if(e.keyCode==8){
        $(this).prev().select();
        return;
    }
})

$(".typinganswer input").on('click', function(e)
{
    $(this).select();
});


})
```

Backspace is not working properly. Help me to fix this.
See in Jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/fasuxofavo/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, when you click <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, both handlers are called, you should just ignore the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> in the `keypress` handler. Put this to the start of the callback:

```
$(".typinganswer input").on('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 8) {
        return;
    }
    ...
});
```

Or if you want to use many different keys, I would recommend using a `switch` statement on the `keyCode`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(e.keyCode!=8){...}
```

around your keypress event actions like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".typinganswer input").on('keypress', function(e)
{
    if(e.keyCode!=8){
    if(e.keyCode==13){
        alert("finish");
    }

    if($(this).val('') !== "")
        $(this).val('');

    if($(this).is(':last-child'))
        $(this).select();

    $(this).next().select();

    }

})
.on('keyup',function(e)
    {
    if(e.keyCode==8){
        $(this).prev().select();
        return;
    }
});

$(".typinganswer input").on('click', function(e)
{
    $(this).select();
});


});
```

Comment: What is actually happening is on key press you are moving forward and on key up back again

Comment: yes, i moving forward, and if press backspace, i moving previous, the previous input will focus and select

Comment: didi you try the code? it works, what I meant to say is on pressing the backspace key you move forward them on keyup back thus staying in one place always